# When is the future?

Tags: ridiculous-fishing

In the Fish-o-pedia in *Ridiculous Fishing*, a few of the fish are listed as only available  by returning to a particular fishing spot in the far future.

Is the far future triggered by some event in game (beating it, purchasing something, etc.), or is this really some date in the future that is unknown at this point?
[image]

Comment: [The future is in the past](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cXQXTeRsnv0)

Comment: Built to last, [the future is the past!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgGBPOC-b3Y)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The far future is triggered by beating the game and watching the end credits. After that, the fish mentioned as available in the far future will show somewhere on the mentioned spots.

For example, one in the screenshot is found in Home Waters, at a depth of 10m, after you've seen the game's credit sequence.

Comment: It sounds like it's triggered by finishing the game then. Any idea on the one in Stormy Seas (also in the Fish-o-pedia, and picture)?

Comment: You have two, don't know which one exactly. One is found in Stormy Seas, at a depth of 300m, after you've seen the game's credit sequence. The other is found in Stormy Seas, at a depth of 400m, after you've seen the game's credit sequence.

Comment: So yeah, you could  hit those in one run if you make it to 400m.

Comment: My question wasn't really about the fish and where they are, it's more about what the trigger was for the far future. It sounds like that it's beating the game and watching the credits. AT least, that's how I think I worded it.

Comment: That is correct. Finish the game and watch the credits, then return to those locations for the fish.

Answer (score 0):

According to the source I found on : http://www.pocketgamer.co.uk/r/iPhone/Ridiculous+Fishing/feature.asp?c=49179

It sais:

> Hint: "Return to Home Waters in the far future."
>
> Solution: Found in Home Waters, at a depth of 10m, after you've seen the game's credit sequence